Search and replace with exceptions list?
The following regular expression in PHP removes all capitalized text at least two characters long.
Is it possible to extend this with a list of capitalized strings that may NOT be removed, like 'GPS' ?
I don't mind the left-over whitespaces as they will be removed with another construct.
<?php

$txt="THIS CAPITALIZED TEXT EXCEPT GPS MUST BE REMOVED and the rest remains in place.";
echo(preg_replace('/\b([A-Z]+){2}\b/','',$txt));

?>

Results in:
and the rest remains in place.

Should result in:
GPS and the rest remains in place.


Yeah, \bGPS\b(*SKIP)(?!)|\b([A-Z]+){2}\b, but \b[A-Z]{2}\b can't match GPS anyway. Maybe two or more except GPS? Then \b(?!GPS\b)([A-Z]+){2,}\b.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback
